# SWIG turns 'bool' C type into a SWIGTYPE, even when including stdbool.h in interface file

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

SWIG generated a SWIGTYPE_p__Bool to use when c functions returned bool types. This seems incorrect.

Example C function returning bool:

```
bool
bitwuzla_sort_is_equal(const BitwuzlaSort *sort0, const BitwuzlaSort *sort1)
{
  BZLA_CHECK_ARG_NOT_NULL(sort0);
  BZLA_CHECK_ARG_NOT_NULL(sort1);
  BZLA_ABORT(sort0->d_bzla != sort1->d_bzla,
             "given sorts are not associated with the same solver instance");

  BzlaSortId bzla_sort0 = BZLA_IMPORT_BITWUZLA_SORT(sort0);
  BzlaSortId bzla_sort1 = BZLA_IMPORT_BITWUZLA_SORT(sort1);
#ifndef NDEBUG
  Bzla *bzla = BZLA_IMPORT_BITWUZLA(sort0->d_bzla);
  assert(bzla_sort_is_valid(bzla, bzla_sort0));
  assert(bzla_sort_is_valid(bzla, bzla_sort1));
#endif

  return bzla_sort0 == bzla_sort1;
}
```

The generated Java wrapper code:

```
  public static SWIGTYPE_p__Bool bitwuzla_sort_is_equal(SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort sort0, SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort sort1) {
    return new SWIGTYPE_p__Bool(bitwuzlaJNI.bitwuzla_sort_is_equal(SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort.getCPtr(sort0), SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort.getCPtr(sort1)), true);
  }
```

The interface file:

```
%module bitwuzla
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "arrays_java.i"

%{
#include "bitwuzla.h"
%}

%apply size_t *OUTPUT { size_t *size };
%inline %{
const BitwuzlaTerm ** bitwuzla_get_unsat_assumptions(Bitwuzla *bitwuzla, size_t *size);
%}

typedef struct Bitwuzla Bitwuzla;

%include "bitwuzla.h"

%include <carrays.i>
%array_functions(BitwuzlaTerm *, bt_array);


%include <stdbool.h>
%include <stdio.h>
%include <stddef.h>
%include <stdarg.h>
%include <stdint.i>
```

Example usage in Java:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort bvsort = bitwuzla.bitwuzla_mk_bv_sort(bzla, 1);
SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaTerm var = bitwuzla.bitwuzla_mk_const(bzla, bvsort, "x" + 1);
SWIGTYPE_p_BitwuzlaSort varSort = bitwuzla.bitwuzla_term_get_sort(var);
assert(bitwuzla.bitwuzla_sort_is_equal(bvsort, varSort));
```

The command for generating the library:
`swig -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -includeall -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include -I/usr/include -java bitwuzla.i`

I tried adding stdbool.h to the interface file, but this didn't resolve the problem. Furthermore, there is a SWIGTYPE_p_bool type, which is never used. This problem could probably be solved using typemaps, but this seems like some misconfiguration or misunderstanding on my end.

Comment: Is there an actual question here??  There's a lot of information, but there's not a specific question to answer on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C99, `bool` is a strange beast, it is a `#define` - if you are compiling in C++ mode it expands to C++ `bool` otherwise it expands to the new primitive type `_Bool` that exists only in C99. This type is not currently recognized by SWIG as a primitive type.

Just map it to `int` and you will be fine:

```
%apply int { _Bool };
```

Your functions will return/expect `0`/`1`.

*or*

You can compile in C++ mode. The C++ `bool` is recognized by SWIG.

*or*

Look at `/usr/local/share/swig/x.x.x/java/java.swg` and copy one line of each typemap (`jni`, `jtype`...) and map it to Java `"bool"`.

Comment: *the new primitive type `_Bool` that exists only in C99*  New?!?! C99? It's old enough to vote and buy alcohol.  It dates to the last **century**, and this **century** is well-nigh 1/4 over already.  I count [at least **71** releases of SWIG since C99 standardized `_Bool`](https://www.swig.org/history.html).